# Regular expression that finds a text between text and dot in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm crawling a web site and it has relative urls and I want to turn them to absolute path.
For this reason, I want to use regular expression.

For example

```
 String text =  new String();
 text +="Lorem Ipsum /image/xyz.jpg"; 
 text +=" Lorem Ipsum /image/xyz2.jpg";
 text +=" Lorem Ipsum /image/xyz2.jpg";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/image\\/.*\\.");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
 while(matcher.find()){
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
 }
```

I want to get  such kind of output:

```
/image/xyz.
/image/xyz2.
/image/xyz2.
```

I think my regex doesnt seem correct. How should I change it to work it properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you wish to achieve? Please supply relevant  input and expected output.

Comment: URI class should have method for this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: You can't absolutize URLs with a regular expression, since the right answer depends on how deep in the tree the current page is. And you could have ../.. embedded. Use the URI class, it exists for a reason.

Comment: I want to change /image/xyz.jpg to  http://xyz.com/image/xyx.jpg
If I express myself wrongly I m sorry but I will use regex for finding such kind of things in my text data. After finding them I will change it

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz: why don't you find all `/image` and replace with `xyz.com/image`?

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz: `/image/.*?\\.` will give you the expected output.

Comment: yes I have asked such question to myself. But I don't know /Image/ or etc. After finding them I want to use this regex to find each link to be replaced.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz: then you can't use `/image` in your regex pattern as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
Pattern.compile("\\/image\\/[^.]*\\.");
```

This is assuming there's only one "." character in the match, ie, no multiple "."s

Comment: You can also add space " " inside the square brackets if you don't want to match it in case there is no dot in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
/.*/\w+\.
```

For the following text:

```
Lorem Ipsum /image/xyz.jpg
```

It will match this

```
/image/xyz.
```

PS: I tested using .NET regular expressions, but this one should work fine in java

Comment: In Java, /.*/\w+\. should be /.*/\\w+\\. and this is still is not working for me